# Filter rows if value exists in different columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We're on SQL Server 2016 and 2019

I have a data-set where I'm rolling up a parent/child relationship. I'm doing this because some of the parent rows will return a `SalesValue` of 0 when their children will the value we're looking for.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT ART.StockCode
     , BOM.Component
     , ART.QtyInvoiced
     , ART.Invoice
     , ART.SalesValue
     , ART2.SalesValue
  FROM TABLE1 ART
  JOIN TABLE2 IM
    ON IM.StockCode = ART.StockCode
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 BOM
    ON BOM.ParentPart = ART.StockCode
   AND IM.KitType = 'K'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE4 ART2
    ON ART2.StockCode = BOM.Component
   AND ART2.Invoice = ART.Invoice
```

And the data it returns

```
StockCode   Component   QtyInvoiced    Invoice     SalesValue   SalesValue2
315128      NULL        1.000000             1         154.32          NULL
317324      NULL        1.000000             1          68.31          NULL
317350      NULL        1.000000             1         428.90          NULL
318482      NULL        1.000000             1         171.24          NULL
320058      NULL        1.000000             1          28.58          NULL
320058      NULL        1.000000             1          28.58          NULL
320058      NULL        1.000000             1          28.58          NULL
900550      NULL        1.000000             1        2396.08          NULL
900572      NULL        1.000000             1        1448.84          NULL
900581      NULL        1.000000             1        2017.96          NULL
901012      900581      1.000000             1           0.00       2017.96
901012      317350      1.000000             1           0.00        428.90
901012      317324      1.000000             1           0.00         68.31
901062      900572      1.000000             1           0.00       1448.84
901062      318482      1.000000             1           0.00        171.24
```

What I'm trying to do is exclude any `StockCode` that has a value in the `Component` field that has the same `Invoice` number

In the example above, we're looking to exclude stock codes 900581, 317350, 317324, 900572, and 318482 because they already exist in the `Component` field.

Here's what I'm going for:

```
StockCode   Component   QtyInvoiced    Invoice     SalesValue   SalesValue2
315128      NULL        1.000000             1         154.32          NULL
320058      NULL        1.000000             1          28.58          NULL
320058      NULL        1.000000             1          28.58          NULL
320058      NULL        1.000000             1          28.58          NULL
900550      NULL        1.000000             1        2396.08          NULL
901012      900581      1.000000             1           0.00       2017.96
901012      317350      1.000000             1           0.00        428.90
901012      317324      1.000000             1           0.00         68.31
901062      900572      1.000000             1           0.00       1448.84
901062      318482      1.000000             1           0.00        171.24
```

Comment: Having worked with BOMs in a previous job, and not having the full picture of your schema, I'm assuming you're trying to determine what assemblies are also components on other BOMs themselves. Not sure if your TABLE1 (ART) table is the complete list of assemblies (StockCodes), but if it isn't, then I would ask the question if you care about any of your ART.StockCodes being a child or even grandchild component to an item not in your ART table? (E.g. If ART doesn't contain all StockCodes, then StockCode 901062 could be the child of StockCode 123456 which could be the child of 900581, etc.)

Comment: That's exactly what it is. What ends up happening is that a customer orders 901062 in our CRM, but in our ERP they're really ordering 900572 and 318482 and the cost of our main part number is zero, so I have to roll those numbers into the main part number

Comment: Ah gotcha, so you're doing a BOM calc for costs. Not sure if an example like 900581 also needs to be costed out since itself is a StockCode besides a Component. Technically your dataset will show the cost of it as a Component, but not sure if you guys add other charges to it when it's sold as an end item (StockCode) or if the cost of its BOM components is different than it's cost? If that's the case then you probably want to get the exploded BOM cost of every end item, and then you'd need to use a recursive CTE. If so, I'll post an example. (This is exactly the problem I solved at my old job.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (your query)
SELECT t1.*
FROM cte t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM cte t2
                   WHERE t1.StockCode = t2.Component )
```

This works by wrapping your original query up into a CTE, then only returning rows from it if there are no other rows where the Component column is equal to the StockCode column.